# Битрикс24. Перехват события отправки формы

Tags: битрикс24

Может знает кто. Есть форма битрикс24 на покупку курса. После ее заполнение и отправки. На битриксе создается сделка с клиентом. И требуется затем сделать редирект на страницу оплаты со всеми данными из формы(email, сумма, ФИО). Как правильно все это реализовать? Перехватить на фронте событие отправки формы с данными из нее(каким способом)? Или через исходящий хук на битрексе?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('b24:form:send:success', function(e) {
    if (e.detail.object.identification.id == <your id>) {
        // do redirect to payment form
    }
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]